# dataexchange between two simultanous running functions in Python

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing

as someone who explores the new and mighty world of Python, I am running into an understanding problem for my coding and it would be great if someone could help me on this one.

To make my problem simple I have made an example.
Lets say, I have two functions, running via multiprocessing simultaneously. One is a permanent data listener and one prints the value of it out. In addition I have one object which owns the data, data is set via set/get. So the challenge is how both function can access the data without putting it to global. I guess my lack of understanding is somewhere in how to transfer the object between functions.

NOTE : both functions do not need to be in sync and the while is just for endless loop. It just how to bring the data over.

This gives a code like (I know it is not working, just to get the idea) :

```
import multiprocessing

#simply a data object
class data(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.__value = 1

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value      

# Data listener
def f1(count):
    zae = 0
    while True:
        zae += 1       
        count.set_value = zae

def f2(count):
    while True:
        print (count.get_value)    

#MainPart
if __name__ == '__main__':
print('start')
count = data()

jobs = []
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target =f1(count))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target =f2(count))
jobs.append(p1)
jobs.append(p2)

p1.start()   
p2.start() 

print ('end')
```

Please enlight me,

regards
AdrianMonk

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a neat case for using memory-mapped files.

When a process memory-maps a file (say F) and another process comes along and maps the same file (i.e maps to F.fileno() too), then exactly the same block of memory is mapped into the second process's address space. This allows the two processes to exchange information extremely rapidly by writing into the shared memory. .

Of course you have to manage the proper access (read,write,etc) in your mappings, and then it is just a matter of properly polling/writing the proper locations in the file to satisfy the logic of your application
(see http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html).

Comment: cool, this sounds like a way to go and it avoids to set everything to global. thx Adrian

Answer (score 0):

The communication channels [Pipe or Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) from `multiprocessing` are designed to solve exactly this kind of problem